# Alternative to "gksu" in "su" mode for non-root users

Tags: permissions, su, oracle-linux, polkit, non-root-user

On an Oracle Linux 8 installation, I am trying to implement a desktop launcher for the GNOME shell where the (graphical) program is to be run as a different (non-root) user. However, I want to enforce password authentication *as the target user*, i.e. a behavior similar to `gksu` in `-w` mode.

The idea is to provide a convenient way for an authorized operator to access the function thanks to knowledge of the target user's password, without unauthorized operators being able to use the program launched.<sup>(1)</sup>

I am aware that `pkexec` is currently the recommended way of launching programs as a different user. Another alternative, `beesu`, [doesn't seem to be available for Oracle Linux 8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/610066/377345).

However, when requiring password-based authentication, *PolKit* only allows to either

- authenticate with the password of the calling user (using `auth_self`), or
- authenticate with the password of an admin user (using `auth_admin`).

I did not find an option to require the password of the target user, as specified in the

```
pkexec --user targetuser /usr/bin/graphical_program
```

command.

**What I tried**

My approach was trying to define the `targetuser` as administrative user *for this individual use case*.  I do not want to globally add the `targetuser` to the list of administrators via the `AdminIdentities` setting in the `[Configuration]` section of the *PolKit* local authority.
So,

- I defined an action in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/` that matches calls of the program via `pkexec` by setting

  ```xml
  <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/graphical_program</annotate>
  ```

  and requiring admin user authentication via

  ```xml
  <defaults>
     <allow_any>no</allow_any>
     <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
     <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
  </defaults>
  ```
- I defined an `AdminRule` in `/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/`, stating

  ```
  polkit.addAdminRule(function(action, subject) {
       if (action.id == "org.my.rule.for.graphical_program") {return ["unix-user:targetuser"];}
       }
  );
  ```

  This should return the `targetuser` as admin user, (only) when the `org.my.rule.for.graphical_program` is asking which user actually is an admin user.

Now, when running `pkexec --user targetuser /usr/bin/graphical_program` I can see that the action is correctly matched (the displayed message is exactly what I set in the `<message> ... </message>` node of the action file), but the `AdminRule` doesn't seem to take effect - the password dialog still requires the *root* password - although the system journal states that the rule was (at least) correctly loaded and compiled, so it shouldn't be a syntax problem.

Does anyone know how (if at all) to get this kind of setting to work using *PolKit*, or what alternative graphical authentication mechanism is available on Oracle Linux 8 (or similar RHEL 8 derivatives)?

---

<sup>(1)</sup>  Note that in this setting, operators can't use individual user accounts, but use generic local user accounts with different privilege levels. Whoever needs the privilege is provided with the password to that specific user account. This is a design decision outside of my control.